# Can an isolation valve be used to reduce pressure?

Tags: plumbing

The pipes going to the shower unit from the boiler both have isolation valves on them, which look like this:

[image]

Can these valves be closed slightly to reduce pressure going through the pipes, or is it advised to only use them in fully open or fully closed positions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They won't reduce the static pressure, just the dynamic pressure when there is water flow. It depends what problem you are trying to solve.

If it is to balance Hot / Cold a bit then yes, closing one a bit will work. It may be a little noisy, but nothing compared to a shower. If your static pressure is too high and you are leaking somewhere then no - it won't make any difference.